# CodeIgniter - Session not working when redirecting to other Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

Session is not working out when redirecting from one controller to another. In below example, I am simply trying to check login and if valid user then set username to session from the Controller named "Login" and redirect to another controller "Testing" and print the session value. But, When the user is validated, session works fine till we are in Login controller (I checked by putting `print_r($this->session->userdata('username'));` by removing redirect method) and when I redirect, the session value shows empty from redirected Controller.

Here is the sample of my code:

Controller: Login.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('M_login');  
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $u=$this->session->userdata('username');
        if($u) {
            redirect('Testing');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
    public function login_form()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
        else{
            $result = $this->M_login->takeUser();
            if(count($result)>0)
            {
                $user = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);

                $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

                redirect('Testing');
            }
            else{
        ?>
            <script>            
            alert('Failed Login: Check your username and password!');       
            history.go(-1);         
            </script>   
        <?php   
            }   
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login/login_form');
    }
}
```

Model: M_login.php

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_login extends CI_Model

{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function takeUser()  
    {   
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password1 = $this->input->post('password');
        $password = md5($password1);

        $this->db->select('username');  
        $this->db->from('employee');    
        $this->db->where('username', $username);    
        $this->db->where('password', $password);    
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->row_array();
    }
}
```

Controller: Testing.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Testing extends CI_Controller
{
     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index() {
        print_r($this->session->userdata('username'));

    }

}
```

Also I have autoload session:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation', 'pagination', 'user_agent','encryption');`

Comment: There's no need to load the session library on each controller if you're already autoloading it. Having said that, `print_r` needs an `echo` or `print` statement before it... Have you tried `print print_r($this->session->userdata('username'));` ?

Comment: Avoid loading session library in controllers. Use autoload array defined in config.php

Comment: @JavierLarroulet: I tried removing session from other controller, i.e. loading session only from autoload, and tried echo or print, but still showing empty result in session.

Comment: @Riosant:  removed loading session library in controllers but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in these lines of code from Login.php

```
$user = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
```

Notice that the variable `$user` is set with the value from `$_POST['username']`, but then contents of `$username` is stored in the session.

Try this

```
$user = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata('username', $user);
```

Answer (score 0):

variable $username is not defined in the login_form() function just change

```
$username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
```

or simply with one line

```
if(count($result)>0)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            redirect('Testing');
        }
```

it's working I checked.